# imported body with html in it color attributes not showing in ckeditor

Tags: html, asp.net-core, ckeditor.net

I upload an html coded file into ckeditor and everything displays fine ( Tables ,text boxs etc,)
but none of the color attributes work for fonts or back grounds. Not sure what's up.

```
        var HTMLBody = "Hello  " + @Model.firmname + " ,";
    
    HTMLBody += "<br><br> Here is a work order for items listed<br><br>";
    HTMLBody += "<style> table, th, td {border: 1px solid black;} </style><table width=600> ";
    HTMLBody += "<TR bgcolor=#22B14C><TD  colspan='2'><center>Work order form</td></TR>";
    HTMLBody += "<TR><TD style='width: 80px'>Hello: </td><TD><font color=black> " + @Model.firmname + "</font></td></TR>";
    HTMLBody += "</table>";
    
    
    HTMLBody += "<style> table, th, td {border: 1px solid black;} </style><table width=600> ";
    HTMLBody += "<TR bgcolor=#EEEEFF><TD  style='width:80px'>Network :<font color=black> </td><TD bgcolor=#FFFFFF> " + @Model.network + "</font></td></TR>";
    HTMLBody += "<TR bgcolor=#EEEEFF><TD  style='width:80px'>Address  :<font color=black> </td><TD bgcolor=#FFFFFF>" + @Model.address + "</font></td></TR>";
    HTMLBody += "<TR bgcolor=#EEEEFF><TD style='width:80px'> Type of Project : <font color=black></td><TD bgcolor=#FFFFFF>" + @Model.typeprojet + "</font></td></TR>";
    HTMLBody += "<TR bgcolor=#22B14C><TD  colspan='2'><center>Work Description</td></TR>";
    
    HTMLBody += "</table>" + "<BR><BR>";

<tr>
            <td colspan="8">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Body)
                
              
                @Html.TextArea("editor", HTMLBody, new { @class = "ckeditor", @id = "Body" })
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Everything displays fine except for the fact there is no color.

Comment: Hi @Peter, what is the version of ckeditor? Besides, `font` should be entirely inside one element(`<p><font color='#800080'>Text</font></p>`), instead of `<td>Address  :<font color=black></td>`.

Comment: Hi Rena , I missed this comment and glad I re-read this post. It turn out you were correct. This code worked fine when I was able to post it to Outlook using application.Outlook in VBA but it doesn't work here. For the background I had to use background-color:green

Answer (score 0):

You need to add color within the style attribute:

```
<td style="width: 80px; color: black; background-color: #fff">Network</td>
```

Comment: Hi , I tried your suggestion and it didn't work. The other options don't work either, like white-space: nowrap , even width : 120px . Yet the tables and <td><tr> tags work fine. Just to be clear , this is using a variable that gathers all the html and is displayed in the  Html.TextArea("editor", HTMLBody, new { class = "ckeditor", id = "Body" }) (had to remove the ampersands)